# AttributeError: 'users_Arduino' object has no attribute 'Progressbar'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I have tried in several ways, set it with ttk.Progressbar, with self.progresso.Progressbar ... and nothing, anyone can help? I'm still young then sorry for ignorance. If they can be as clear as possible, thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

class users_Arduino:

    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("System F2T - Cadastro Arduino")

        menubar = Menu(window)
        arduino = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Arduino",menu=arduino)
        arduino.add_command(label = "Conectar/Inserir dados-BD", command=self.getSerialData)
        window.config(menu = menubar)

    def bar(): 
        progress['value'] = 20
        root.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(1) 

        progress['value'] = 40
        root.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(1) 

        progress['value'] = 50
        root.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(1) 

        progress['value'] = 60
        root.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(1) 

        progress['value'] = 80
        root.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(1) 
        progress['value'] = 100   

    def getSerialData(self):
        self.progresso = Toplevel()
        self.progresso.title("System F2T - Progress")
        self.progresso.geometry("290x200")
        #self.progresso["bg"] = "#000"
        progress = self.Progressbar(self.progresso,orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'determinate').pack(pady = 10) 
        Button(self.progresso, text = 'Start', command = self.bar).pack(pady = 10) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window['bg'] = "#000"
    users_Arduino(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a class attribute by using `self.Progressbar`, which obviously won't work. What you intended is to create a `Progressbar`, which should be done like below:

```
progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.progresso,orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'determinate').pack(pady = 10)
```

Next, you wanted the Progressbar to update every second until it reaches 100, but calling `time.sleep` will block your main thread and freeze your GUI. You need to use `root.after` method.

Also if you call `something=widget(...).pack()` at the same line, you are not keeping a proper reference of the object. The return value will just be `None`.

So everything wrapped up:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class UsersArduino:

    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("System F2T - Cadastro Arduino")
        self.value = 0
        menubar = Menu(window)
        arduino = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Arduino",menu=arduino)
        arduino.add_command(label = "Conectar/Inserir dados-BD", command=self.getSerialData)
        window.config(menu = menubar)

    def bar(self):
        self.progress['value'] +=20
        if self.progress['value'] <=100:
            self.wind.after(1000,self.bar)

    def getSerialData(self):
        self.progresso = Toplevel()
        self.progresso.title("System F2T - Progress")
        self.progresso.geometry("290x200")
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.progresso,orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'determinate')
        self.progress.pack(pady = 10)
        Button(self.progresso, text = 'Start', command = self.bar).pack(pady = 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window['bg'] = "#000"
    UsersArduino(window)
    window.mainloop()
```